# When I try to checkout a project I get Unusable URI: it does not refer to this repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

today I'm trying to checkout a svn project, and when I go to repo URL in tortoiseSvn I see the project structure online, but when I use checkout I always get:

Unusable URI: it does not refer to this repository

and nothing is downloaded.

Any point?¿

Thanks in advance,

Tomás García

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed to be a local network issue.  Repository was not accesible through local network, but public network.

To access inside I had to use internal IP.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the URL you're using to try the checkout is the URL of the web viewer. Usually hosted projects offer two URLs: one for browsing the repository with a webbrowser that also offers syntax highlighting and some other stuff, and the URL to the repository.

To do a checkout, you have to find the URL to the repository.

Comment: I think both URL's point to repository, but inside the office we have a "strange" redirection and complex network configuration.

Thanks for your answer!